# Breeze server side validation from Controller

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have an Entity, say "Car", that has many relationships with other entities. One of the relationships is with entity "ParkingSpot". The relationship in the Entity Framework is 1 car to Many ParkingSpots,but it is always 1-to-1, just 1-to-many in the EF which is another story.

I'd like to a Server Side delete method that does the following -

1. Do error checking (on all FK constrained relationships except ParkingSpot), provider user friendly errors
2. Remove this Car from ParkingSpot (so delete works if all other constraint errors pass)
3. Delete Car

Right now I have method

```
[HttpGet]
public bool DeleteCar(int carId)
```

am throwing an HttpResponseException per each error.  So the user could get an error, fix the problem, try again, get another error,etc. which is kind of lame.  I tried throwing an EntityErrorsException with a colleciton of EFEntityErrors as outlined here- http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/server-side-validation

But it only came through as a JSON string in the data of the httpresponse, maybe because it wasn't done in the BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate  as shown in the article?  I can't really do it here, because other cases call for deleting this Entity in other ways in which you would want the "ParkingSpot" constraint to fail.

What is the best way to provide this kind of validation?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you can't do the validation in `BeforeSaveEntities`. I suspect you will discover a way to do it there.

Comment: @david004 - In one scenario, i need to remove the Car from the ParkingSpot, then delete the car. In other scenarios I want the delete to fail if it is in a ParkingSpot.  So I really have another param for this scenario public bool DeleteCar(int carId, bool removeFromSpot)